# Calculate the limit of the sequence $\left(\frac{2^{2n+1}-3^n+\log{(n)}}{2^{2n}+1}\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$

Tags: calculus

Calculate the limit of the sequence $\left(\frac{2^{2n+1}-3^n+\log{(n)}}{2^{2n}+1}\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.
Would I just divide the top and bottom by $2^{2n} = 4^n$ then take the limit?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

$$\frac{2^{2n+1}-3^n+\log(n)}{2^{2n}+1}=\frac{2\cdot4^n-3^n+\log(n)}{4^n+1}=\frac{2-\frac{3^n}{4^n}+\frac{\log(n)}{4^n}}{1+\frac{1}{4^n}}$$

Now take the limit as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much.